# Find all pairs of unique indices in a list such that the concatenation of the two words is a palindrome

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

**The task**

> Given a list of words, find all pairs of unique indices such that the
>   concatenation of the two words is a palindrome.
>
> For example, given the list `["code", "edoc", "da", "d"]`, return 
>   `[(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 3)]`.

```
const lst = ["code", "edoc", "da", "d"];
```

**My functional solution**

```
const findPalindromePairs = lst => {
  const isPalindrome = str => str === [...str].reverse().join("");
  return lst.reduce((pairs, w1, i) => {
    return [...pairs, ...lst.reduce((match, w2, j) => {
      if (i !== j && isPalindrome(`${w1}${w2}`)) { match.push([i,j]); }
      return match;
    }, [])];
  }, []);
};

console.log(findPalindromePairs(lst));
```

**My imperative solution**

```
function findPalindromePairs2 (lst) {
  const len = lst.length;
  const pairs = [];

  const isPalindrome = str => str === [...str].reverse().join("");
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {
      if (i !== j && isPalindrome(lst[i] + lst[j])) { pairs.push([i,j]); }
    }
  }
  return pairs;
}

console.log(findPalindromePairs2(lst));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see anything that jumps out as an obvious simplification. I looked online for other code for this task and only found one [in python](https://github.com/vineetjohn/daily-coding-problem/blob/master/solutions/problem_167.py) which uses the same basic algorithm.

The only suggestion I have is for readability, the name `match` in the functional solution might be slightly confusing for anyone reading the code. Perhaps a more appropriate name would be something like `subMatches`.

I did notice that the functional solution concatenates the strings with a template literal, while the imperative solution uses traditional string concatenation. Why not just use the traditional technique in the functional solution? The results of [this jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/template-literal-vs-string-plus/7) show negligible differences between the two approaches.

Comment: I try to use and combine different techniques to see what sticks.